# Homework - Getting Started - Optimization

Tags: optimization

I am starting up my Masters after being out of school for awhile and this is my first week back. I am recalling how to complete a problem and I am wondering if anyone can help me get started. I do not need a final answer, just steps needed to complete.

**Problem**: Solve the following optimization problem using Lagrange multiplier. Express your answer in terms of $A, b,$ and $y$.

minimize $x$, $||x-y||^2$
subject to $Ax=b$

**Attempt**

$$L(x,\lambda) = ||x-y||^2 + \lambda^T(Ax -b)$$
$$L(x,\lambda) = ||x-y||^2 + \lambda^TAx -\lambda^Tb$$

Now, do I take a partial derivative with respect to $x$? For clarity, below is an image of the problem.

---

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please use MathJax for to write your problem and in addition to that, show what you have tried to solve the problem and where the problem solvers here we can help you.

Comment: Is $y$ given? We need some context and a try from you.

Comment: I added more information above. y is not given. It is just a variable.

Comment: Is $A$ a square matrix?

Comment: I added a picture of the problem for clarity.

Comment: FWIW, this problem has a nice geometric interpretation too: find the point in the affine subspace $S=\{x\mid Ax=b\}$ closest to $y$. The answer is the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto $S$ (maybe helpful to draw a 2D example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but the derivative of the langrangian with respect to x is $2(x-y)+A^\intercal \lambda=0$ and the derivative with respect to $\lambda$ is $Ax-b=0$.

This solution assumes that y is given and at some point that A is a square matrix, but it should work even if A is not square if the last few steps are omitted.

From the first equation, $x=\frac 1 2 (-A^\intercal\lambda+y)$. Putting this in the second equation,$\frac 1 2 A(-A^\intercal\lambda+y)-b=0$. So $-\frac 1 2 AA^\intercal\lambda+\frac 1 2Ay=b$. So $\lambda=-2(AA^\intercal)^{-1}(b-\frac 1 2 Ay)$. Putting this back in what we got from the first equation, we eventually get $x=\frac 1 2(-A^\intercal(-2)(AA^\intercal)^{-1}(b-\frac 1 2 Ay)+y)=\frac 1 2(2A^{-1}b-y+y)=A^{-1}b$